# antlr4 Java get found tokens map?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

How can i retrieve found tokens map (something like `[{'identifier','x'},{'number',15}...]`) so I can verify that text have been mapped correctly to tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Your generated lexer has a [`getAllTokens()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#getAllTokens()) methods that, not surprisingly, returns all tokens from your provided input.